# Docker container can't be reached

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up a node.js application to run in docker. I know the application works because if I run it on my mac, I can reach the landing page on port 8081.

However, when launching a docker container, it shows the container running, but I cannot reach it.  Dockerfile has command:

> EXPORT 8081

docker ps output shows the following:

> COMMAND: "npm start"
>
> STATUS: Up 3 minutes
>
> 0.0.0.0:45444->8081/tcp

Going to localhost:45444 or 0.0.0.0:45444 does not work.

Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Adding the Dockerfile per request below:

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! How did you run your Docker container?